# pd.to_csv saves, but apparently the wrong data (according to print function)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

this is my first post on stackoverflow. Please be easy on me, if I don't follow the common styleguide correctly.

I am doing the kaggle challenge "predict house_prices". My first step is to preprocess the dataset. There are empty cells in the code "NaN". With df["Headline"].fillNA("NA") I change it to "NA" which, in this challenge, is defined as not further described.

The print function shows, that the approach works. At the end of it, I want to save my modified DataFrame into a .csv file (you can see path and filename in the code).
However, while the .csv does indeed save, the data apparently is wrong. So, I guess I must've done a mistake with the syntax of pd.to_csv.

First, here's my code. Afterwards, you find what the console says about the modified dataframe "maindf" and the dataframe of my .csv file "csvdf". Sorry for the poor formatting with the console by the way.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Variables
PRICE = []
CRIT = []

#Directories
DATADIR = r"C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Project_Arcus\house_price\data"
DATA = "train.csv"
path = os.path.join(DATADIR, DATA)
MODFILE = "train_modified.csv"
mod_path = os.path.join(DATADIR, MODFILE)

print(f"Training Data is {path}")
print(f"Modified Training Data is{mod_path}")

# Goal: Open the document of the chosen path. Extract data (f. e. the headline)
df = pd.read_csv(path)
maindf = df # this step is unnecessary, but it helped me to better understand.

# Goal: Check for empty cells. Replace them with a fitting value, so the neural network can 
# threat them accordingly. Save the .csv under a new name.
maindf["PoolQC"] = df["PoolQC"].fillna("NA")
maindf["MiscFeature"] = df["MiscFeature"].fillna("NA")
maindf["Alley"] = df["Alley"].fillna("NA")
maindf["Fence"] = df["Fence"].fillna("NA")
maindf["FireplaceQu"] = df["FireplaceQu"].fillna("NA")
maindf.to_csv(mod_path,index=True) # index=False means there will be no row names (index).

# Next Goal: Save the dataframe df into a csv document "train_modified.csv"  WORKS
# Check if the new file is correct.                                     Not correct! NaN included...!

#print(df.isnull().sum())
csvdf = pd.read_csv(mod_path)
#print(csvdf.isnull().sum())
print(maindf["PoolQC"].head(10))
print(csvdf["PoolQC"].head(10))
```

> Training Data is
>   C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Project_Arcus\house_price\data\train.csv 
>   Modified Training Data is
>   C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Project_Arcus\house_price\data\train_modified.csv
>   0    NA 1    NA 2    NA 3    NA 4    NA 5    NA 6    NA 7    NA 8
>   NA 9    NA Name: PoolQC, dtype: object 0
>   NaN 1    NaN 2    NaN 3
>   NaN 4    NaN 5    NaN 6    NaN 7    NaN 8    NaN 9    NaN Name:
>   PoolQC, dtype: object

Comment: please take to some to read this and adjust your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't with `to_csv`, it's with `read_csv`, the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for which states:

> **na_values** : scalar, str, list-like, or dict, default None
>
> By default the following values are interpreted as NaN: ‘’, ‘#N/A’,
>   ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’, ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’,
>   ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘N/A’, **‘NA’**, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘n/a’, ‘nan’, ‘null’.

Instead, define `keep_default_na` and `na_values` arguments when you use `read_csv`:

```
csvdf = pd.read_csv(mod_path, keep_default_na=False, na_values='')
```

You may wish to supply a list of values for `na_values`: if used with `keep_default_na=False`, Pandas will consider *only those values* as `NaN`.

A better idea is to use a less ambiguous string than `'NA'` to represent data you don't want to be read as `NaN`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly as requested! This would've taken me a rather long time.